# Move cursor to closest specific symbol in Intellij Idea or Visual Studio Code IDEs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

say I have following JSON structure:

```
          "broken clouds":"poloblačno",
          "clear sky":"číra obloha",
          "few clouds":"nízka oblačnost",
          "fog":"mračno",
          "haze":"mierna hmla",
          "heavy intensity rain":"intenzívne pršanie",
          "heavy snow":"intenzívne sneženie",
          "light intensity drizzle":"mrholenie slabej intenzitz",
          "light rain":"mierny dážď",
          "light rain and snow":"mierne pršanie a sneženie",
          "light shower snow":"mierne prehánky",
          "light snow":"mierne sneženie",
          "mist":"hmlisto",
          "moderate rain":"stredný dážď",
          "overcast clouds":"zatiahnute",
          "scattered clouds":"rozptýlené oblaky",
          "smoke":"dymenie",
          "snow":"sneženie"
```

Say I want to copy keys only.
I can select multiple lines by creating more cursors with 'ALT+SHIFT+ARROW UP/DOWN'
Since my keys have uneven number of spaces between them, selecting all text till ':' symbol with 'CTRL+SHIFT+ARROW LEFT/RIGHT' is with my knowledge not doable.
How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ctrl + F** - type your symbol, then press **alt+enter**

Works in VS code and Webstorm

Comment: This is in visual studio code, where did you try it?

Comment: VS, idea and vim. what is your alt + space set to? maybe my shortcut isnt set

Comment: @Marius I am sorry, I typed it wrong, its alt+enter

Comment: thank you, this is the correct answer. In addition, is there a way to limit the find to a scope? say I want to find all references to a symbol within a method, or selected brackets?

Comment: Glad I could help. I guess it can be done with regex, but I cant help there. In the meantime you can just copy the method in a new file, change it there and copy it back